# Retornar o valor de uma função async

Tags: javascript, async

Olá, estou me batendo pra escrever o codigo abaixo

```
const request = require('request-promise')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
var fs = require('fs')
const URL ='https://shadowarena.pearlabyss.com/en-US/Arena?battleType=0&server=sa'
async function  rankingYoda(){
    let rankYoda;
    let ranks = []
    const response = await request(URL)
    const $ = cheerio.load(response)
    $('.box_list_area').each((i, e) => {
        const name = $(e).find('.thum_name').text()
        ranks.push(name)

    })
    for(var i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++){
        if(ranks[i]=== "YoDaSL"){
            rankYoda = i+1
        }
    }

}
rankingYoda()
```

Como faço para a função `async` retornar o valor da variavel `rankYoda`, e não retorne `[object Promise]` to tentando faz alguns dias resolver isso, mas não consigo.

Comment: Utilize o operador `await` ou use-a como uma `promise`

Comment: Como posso colocar o operador `await`?

Comment: Você pode fazer como [neste código](https://pastebin.com/pftz3k6x) ou, no seu caso, utilizar a biblioteca [sync-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request)

Answer (score 0):

Só podes usar `await` dentro de funções assíncronas. Para usar de outra maneira tens de usar a API de Promise.

Ou seja, quando usas assim dá erro:

```js
async function foo() {
  return 'bar';
}

const string = await foo(); 
// Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Se usares assim já vai funcionar:

```
async function  foo() {
  return 'bar';
}

foo().then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: P.S.: Só lembrando que dessa forma, a variável `string` ainda será uma `promise`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr exato, eram restos de copiar o código da pergunta. Corrigi, obrigado :)